# C# Multiple downloads with webclient

Tags: download

I have a download list into a txt file. (http://launcher.dryadmu.com/Update/ArchiveList.txt)
And it check if crc32 has changed, and only then download the file to the client, the problem is that it takes too long when the list grows.
The download class:

```
 class FileDownloader
{
    private static int curFile;
    private static long lastBytes;
    private static long currentBytes;

    private static Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

    public static void DownloadFile()
    {
        if (Globals.OldFiles.Count <= 0)
        {
            Common.ChangeStatus("CHECKCOMPLETE");
            Common.UpdateCompleteProgress(100);
            Common.StartGame();
            return;
        }

        if (curFile >= Globals.OldFiles.Count)
        {
            Common.ChangeStatus("DOWNLOADCOMPLETE");
            Common.StartGame();
            return;
        }

        if (Globals.OldFiles[curFile].Contains("/"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(Globals.OldFiles[curFile]));
        }

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadProgressChanged);

        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadFileCompleted);

        stopWatch.Start();

        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(Globals.ServerURL + Globals.OldFiles[curFile]), Globals.OldFiles[curFile]);
    }

    private static void webClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        currentBytes = lastBytes + e.BytesReceived;

        Common.ChangeStatus("DOWNLOADFILE", Globals.OldFiles[curFile], curFile.ToString(), Globals.OldFiles.Count.ToString());

        Common.UpdateCompleteProgress(Computer.Compute(Globals.completeSize + currentBytes));

        Common.UpdateCurrentProgress(e.ProgressPercentage, Computer.ComputeDownloadSpeed(e.BytesReceived, stopWatch));

    }

    private static void webClient_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        lastBytes = currentBytes;

        Common.UpdateCurrentProgress(100, 0);

        curFile++;

        stopWatch.Reset();

        DownloadFile();
    }
}
```

I couldn't figured out how to add DownloadFileTaskAsync. Any help would be appreciated. Thx

Comment: You should know where the limitation is. If you are using all available bandwith there isnt really any benefith of paralell downloading. But if you are downloading from many different sources where your bandwith is higher then what they provide, you can run paralell downloads.

Comment: Hi @MrZach, thx for the answer. The bandwitch isn't a problem, they are mostly files under 500kb. The problem is current code download only 1 file at the time. I would appreciate any tip on how to implement the async download to the current code.